# Visual Studio Incorrectly Displays Barcode Font In RDLC Reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, rdlc

I have the following issue: I have a windows form app where I print reports and they are supposed to have barcodes on them. When I am in the .rdlc file designer the barcode shows like this: [image]

(The weird crossed out circles I assume is from the square brackets and the @ symbol because data is coming from a parameter).
So when I print this out, everything prints out fine, but the thing is, the barcode font I am using is supposed to also have text underneath like this: [image]

Now when I go into Word and type in the same barcode font (I triple checked it is the same) it behaves as expected
I looked all over the place but there are literally no posts anywhere that I could find that would help me besides [this one by Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-barcode-font-is-displayed-incorrectly-in-a-report-created-by-using-a-report-viewer-2010-control-when-you-export-the-report-to-pdf-format-1a2eecdd-21a7-8044-690a-cabc237df867) It just tells me I need that .dll file but I already have it and still same results.

UPDATE: so the other report that also has barcodes works just fine, the barcodes that work are: `*1868210325S0000100004* , *S00001+000001+00004+FIEG0P01* , *EDG20210325000374570*`

barcode that does NOT work: `*JLI-0253932*`
it takes the value from a parameter "liNumber" which is populated like so:

```
parameters[6] = new ReportParameter("liNumber", "J" + fidelity.liNumber, true);
```

where `fidelity.liNumber` returns `LI-0253932`

But what I don't understand is that all working barcodes are populated in a similar fashion

Comment: most of the times I have run into that, it was due to data.  Barcode fonts may not have value for lower-case content or special characters.

Comment: @DRapp its supposed to be displaying something like this: JLI-0253932 do any of this characters seem to be the culprit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreating the parameter in both .cs file like so

```
string jliNumber = "J" + fidelity.liNumber;
parameters[6] = new ReportParameter("liNumber", jliNumber, true);
```

and then in the report .rdlc file just deleting and creating the same parameter again worked for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times I have run into that, it was due to data.  Barcode fonts may not have value for lower-case content or special characters.

I would make a copy of your report for backup, copy the detail since you have space between the detail rows.  In the second instance, change the font back to a normal / simple font like Courier.  Then print the report again.  Check to see the ACTUAL values being printed in normal font vs your barcode font.  I would bet they are upper/lower / special characters and spaces that the barcode does NOT have included in it.

Additionally, every time you run the report, write the actual values out to a text file and just keep appending text.  Then, you can open the text file in Word or whatever editor, select all text, then change the font to the barcode.  Do you get the same bad results.